# How do i apply a translation after a rotation without changing the direction of the translation?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I'm trying to apply a translation to the model matrix of an entity in my OpenGL program, but if i apply the translation after applying a scale or a rotation to the model matrix, i get different results from what i would expect: applying a translation after a scale results in the translation being multiplied by the scale, applying a translation after a rotation results in the translation being applied on a different direction.
I understand how the matrices at play work and how they change the model matrix, so i used this implementation to revert the changes before applying a translation:

```
void Entity::scale(float scaleFactor) {
  this->modelMatrix = glm::scale(this->modelMatrix, glm::vec3(scaleFactor));
  this->scaleFactor *= scaleFactor;
}

void Entity::move(glm::vec3 position, glm::mat4 viewMatrix) {
  float oldScaleFactor = this->scaleFactor;
  float oldRotateFactorX = this->rotateFactorX;
  float oldRotateFactorY = this->rotateFactorY;
  float oldRotateFactorZ = this->rotateFactorZ;

  scale(1 / this->scaleFactor);

  rotate(-this->rotateFactorX, -this->rotateFactorY, -this->rotateFactorZ);

  this->modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, position);

  glm::mat4 worldModelMatrix = glm::inverse(viewMatrix) * (viewMatrix * this->modelMatrix);

  this->worldPosition.x = worldModelMatrix[3][0];
  this->worldPosition.y = worldModelMatrix[3][1];
  this->worldPosition.z = worldModelMatrix[3][2];

  rotate(oldRotateFactorX, oldRotateFactorY, oldRotateFactorZ);

  scale(oldScaleFactor);
}

void Entity::rotate(float x, float y, float z) {
  this->rotateFactorX += x;
  this->rotateFactorY += y;
  this->rotateFactorZ += z;
  this->modelMatrix = glm::rotate(this->modelMatrix, glm::radians(x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  this->modelMatrix = glm::rotate(this->modelMatrix, glm::radians(y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
  this->modelMatrix = glm::rotate(this->modelMatrix, glm::radians(z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

basically i revert the scale and rotate operations before applying the translation, and then put them back as they were before.
This implementation works for the scale, but it doesn't work for the rotation, which results in an increase of rotation speed that gets out of control (meaning the rotation factor constantly increases).
Am i reverting the rotation correctly? or even better: is there a better way to separate the 3 operations without having them interact with each other?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out i was applying the transformations in the wrong order (scale before rotation) when trying to revert the changes. To avoid having to revert the changes alltogether you can just set up 3 different identity matrices (one for translation, one for rotation and one for scale) and apply the correct transformation to each matrix individually, and then multiply the 3 matrices together to get the model matrix, order is important:
model = translation * rotation * scale
this way you always apply the transformations in the correct order and you don't have to worry about the 3 transformations interfeering with each other

Comment: Nice. Why would the order of operations matter though? Intuitively, it should not matter if points are moved before or after scaling, no?

Comment: the problem is that applying transformations means multiplying matrices, and matrix multiplication is not commutative (not sure if it's called like that in english). basically if you have matrix A and matrix B, A * B != B * A. so applying transformations in different orders makes it so that the final matrix is different